# Current location in auto-complete without Google Places?

Tags: android, autocomplete, location

I'm currently in the making of an android application, with autocomplete from some fixed strings array.

When the user press on the auto complete text view, I want that a menu with "current location" option will be opened as default (before the user even started to type), but I'm not using Google Places (as the values of the auto-complete is from the array), so how can I do this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to show is a `default suggestion` in your `AutocompleteTextView`.

suppose you have an AutocompleteTextView named locationAutoComplete.
You can show default suggestion by

```
  locationAutoComplete.setText("current location");
```

But there is a problem in `AutocompleteTextview` to show `default suggestion` using `setText(String str)`; method directly. Whenever `setText(String str)` method is called it disables the `AutocompleteTextView`.

To prevent it write your code as below.

```
    locationAutoComplete.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            locationAutoComplete.showDropDown();
        }
    },500);
    locationAutoComplete.setText("current location");
    locationAutoComplete.setSelection(locationAutoComplete.getText().length());
```

Comment: thank you, but I don't want it to appear in the text, I want that when the user press on the auto-complete text view, a menu will be opened and there will be an option of "current location". do you know how to do that?

Comment: I think i can help you.But please give the opportunity help you first.Edit the question and add some code of your activity.Then me or anybody will be able to help you correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using a fixed set of strings, you can use [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html):

```
String[] yourStrings; // However you get your strings

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, yourStrings);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
    findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: how to make a default "current location" option in the menu?

Comment: You have full control over the list, so just add it to your list.

Comment: but I want it to appear before the user even started to type any letter